# Convert rows to columns using pivot and in clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have two tables t1 and t2

t1:

```
object_id date
123       11/10/2014
```

t2:

```
object_id   employee_id
123            abc
123            xyz
123            def
456            ghi
```

I would like to display result as

```
123 11/10/2014 abc xyz def
456 11/10/2014 ghi
```

i.e., new columns for each employee name

How to do this using pivot and in clause?

Comment: Could you please create an example at sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: Hi Dmitry i'm not familiar with sql fiddle

Comment: Do you know that there will always be at most three rows in `t2` for any particular object_id?  How do you determine how to order the three values?  Is there a particular reason that you need to use the `pivot` operator?

Comment: @shady Go to sqlfiddle.com, choose `Oracle 11.2` in menu at the top, in left part write statements `create table` for your tables, `insert` statements to populate tables with your data, then take link (at the bottom of the page) and write this link here.

Comment: Hi Justin- No the number of rows may vary by object id

Comment: @shady I know you want to use the pivot feature, but your requirement looks like the listagg function used as an aggregate would suit you better.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you need to use the `pivot` operator?  If you're trying to aggregate an unknown number of strings, `pivot` is not the right approach.  Does anything actually require that you use `pivot` rather than some other technique?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need pivot. You can simply join your tables and use listagg function.

There is a sample in [this link](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515).

http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515

In your sample it will be like

```
LISTAGG(employee_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY object_id) AS employees
```